# In triangle $ABC$, $\angle A=50^{\circ}$. Point $D$ is constructed inside the triangle such that $\angle BDC=130^{\circ}$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

(I know my diagrams are awful, but I tried my best.)

Question: In triangle $ABC$, $\angle A=50^{\circ}$. Point $D$ is constructed inside the triangle such that $\angle BDC=130^{\circ}$. $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$, and $AB=CD$. What is $\angle DCB$?

[image]

My first thought was to use the trig form of Ceva's theorem, but because we're given the equality $AB=CD$ instead of other angles, I'm not quite sure how to apply it.

Using the fact that $\angle A+\angle BDC=180^{\circ}$, I was thinking that if I constructed the circumcircle of $\Delta BDC$, then if I picked a point $G$ on minor arc $BC$, then $\angle A=\angle CGB$.

[image]

Because we're given that $AD \perp BC$, $AD$ is an altitude of $\Delta ABC$, I was considering the possibility that reflecting $D$ over $BC$ would create the orthocenter of $\Delta BCG$. However, I doubt this is true.

Comment: Really $AB=CD$? That's not very obvious from the diagrams...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Reflect $A$ about $BC$. Let the image of $A$ be $X$.

Since $\angle BXC=\angle BAC=50^\text{o}$, $\angle BDC+\angle BXC=130^\text{o}+50^\text{o}=180^\text{o}$.

$\therefore B, D, C, X$ are concyclic.

We can draw the circle as shown.

Note that $BX=BA$. Hence $CD=BX$ and  $\angle CXD=\angle BCX $.

$\because \angle BCX + \angle CXD=90^\text{o},$

$\therefore \angle BCX =45^\text{o}$.

$\therefore \angle BXD=50^\text{o}-45^\text{o}=5^\text{o}$

Finally $\angle BCD=\angle BXD=5^\text{o}$